# DbContext SaveChanges throws InvalidOperationException with Identity Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, primary-key

I have `Book` entity with a **string** `ID` key which is calculated in a `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER` and will be returned back to EF by including the generated value in a `Select` inside the trigger.

```
  Property(c => c.ID)
    .HasMaxLength(100)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

After adding new entities to the store via `DbSet.Add` method I get the following exception once I call either of these:

- context.Books.Local
- context.Books.Find(id);
- context.SaveChanges();
- context.GetValidationErrors();

**Exception:**

```
The key field 'ID' cannot have a value of null. 
A non-null value is required for the key fields defined on type 'Book'.
```

When I have set it as `Identity` why `SaveChanges()` is not happy with the null key?